# How to access hidden CSS classes from CSS modules in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

I'm new to React. So I found out that there is a CSS mixing problem going on in my React code. So I used CSS modules to solve that problem. But when I'm doing a frontend React JS project with Bootsrap, I came up with this problem.

[image]

So In this Carousel component, there are hidden(those are only shown in compiled HTML files) CSS classes called carousel-control-next and carousel-control-prev. So I need to change their CSS styles with CSS modules. So how can I access them?

[image]

I imported this CSS module file as a CSS module in my React file, but it's not working. Can someone help me with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `:global` to get not modular styles such as styles for Carousel

https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#exceptions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But what If we have two CSS files for two react files, like that and we have to use different stylings for those components that are declared in a third-party library you're importing, so you might have no control. When I add global I saw that the stylings are going for all of those two files. But I need to control those classes differently.

Comment: As an example, I need to access that carousel-control-next class and need two different styles in two files. But the thing is that the carousel-control-next class cannot be controlled normally because it's inside that Bootstrap carousel.

Comment: oh, I found out the answer for that. I just applied two different classes for parent's elements of those classes and referenced them in that CSS class with that uncontrollable CSS class.